# Ternary Operator vs. If/Else in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, logic

Is there any difference between using an `if/else` statement and the `ternary operator` in Objective C in terms of speed? Are they identical in compiled code?

That is, is there any reason to use one of the following over the other, other than to save space?

```
//First Option
Object *myObj = boolean ? trueValue : falseValue;

//Second Option
Object *myObj;
if (boolean) {
    myObj = trueValue;
else {
    myobj = falseValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there may be minor differences in compiled code, there is no reason other than readability to prefer one way to the other.

One advantage of the `if`/`else` approach is that you can set up multiple variables with a single condition:

```
Object *myObj1;
Object *myObj2;
if (boolean) {
    myObj1 = trueValue1;
    myObj2 = trueValue1;
else {
    myobj1 = falseValue2;
    myobj2 = falseValue2;
}
```

Since boolean in Objective-C is a numeric type with values 0 and 1, there is an approach that does not rely on conditionals at all:

```
Object *valArray[] = { falseValue, trueValue };
Object *myObj = valArray[boolean];
```

Comment: The array method is not safe.  True values are not constrained to be exactly 1, and the value will depend on how the boolean is created.

Comment: @Avi Although it is certainly true that Obj-C would interpret any non-zero value as boolean true, all logical operators are required to return zero or one. When one is not sure of the origin of his boolean, he could apply the double exclamation point trick, i.e. !!boolean.